# Postgres function not returning the out parameters as expected

Tags: django, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am writing a function in postgres sql to check if eamil is in the table or not. if exists then check status.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_email_status_from_master_list(IN email_to_check character varying, OUT already_exists boolean, OUT dosend boolean)
AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
already_exists boolean := False;
doSend boolean := False;
status character varying(255);
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT true FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check) THEN
  -- do something
  already_exists := True;
  SELECT email_status INTO status FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check;
  --SELECT sendmessage_master_list_emails into status FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check;
  if(status='Bounce') then
  doSend := False;
  elsif(status='Invalid Email') then
  doSend := False;
  elsif(status='Delivered') then
  doSend :=True;
  else
  doSend := False;
  end if;
ELSE
already_exists := False;
doSend := False;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I called this function from django by passing three emails. where first two emails are not in the database and the last one is in the database and status is Bounce.

```
users = {1 : { "name" : "M user", "email" : "abc.official@gmail.com" , "phone" : "123456456"},
     2 : { "name" : "M user", "email" : "abc.official@gmail.com" , "phone" : "1234564569" },
     3 : { "name" : "M user", "email" : "abc.xyz@gmail.com" , "phone" : "1234564565" }}

     # Check First if the email is invalid & spam from the master list
    for keys in users:
        c = connection.cursor()
        try:
            c.execute("BEGIN")
            c.callproc("check_email_status_from_master_list", [users[keys]["email"]])
            resultss = c.fetchall()
            c.execute("COMMIT")
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        finally:
            for item in resultss:
                print item
            c.close()
```

the function returns the output like this instead of false or true.

```
(None, None)
(None, None)
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason OUT isn't working as expected is because you are **redeclaring** the two variables in the DECLARE section.

The two lines highlighted below, should be in the BEGIN/END block and **not** in the DECLARE block. When in the DECLARE block, the parser considers this as two local variables (just with the same name as the OUT variables). This is the reason why, when returning the OUT variables are NULLs and therefore you get an empty output.

Here is the sample Function with the said change:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_email_status_from_master_list(IN email_to_check character varying, OUT already_exists boolean, OUT dosend boolean)
AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
status character varying(255);
BEGIN
already_exists := False; -- MOVE THESE LINES FROM DECLARE ... to BEGIN/END block
doSend := False;         -- MOVE THESE LINES FROM DECLARE ... to BEGIN/END block
IF EXISTS(SELECT true FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check) THEN
  -- do something
  already_exists := True;
  SELECT email_status INTO status FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check;
  --SELECT sendmessage_master_list_emails into status FROM sendmessage_master_list_emails WHERE email=email_to_check;
  if(status='Bounce') then
  doSend := False;
  elsif(status='Invalid Email') then
  doSend := False;
  elsif(status='Delivered') then
  doSend :=True;
  else
  doSend := False;
  end if;
ELSE
already_exists := False;
doSend := False;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I have added `RETURNS SETOF  boolean` but is says `function result type must be record because of OUT parameters`

Comment: then i have also added RETURNS SETOF record but return empty list as a result

Comment: Have updated the response with a working code-base. Hope this helps to explain why the earlier solution wasn't working.